# visual basic checkedlistbox to listbox

Tags: vb.net

I am new to visual basic and am trying to create a program where selected task in a checkedlistbox make a list of supplies in a listbox, but I am having no luck.
My questions, is: can you call a string stored in an array to display in a listbox by checking an item in a checkedlistbox? 
I have it set so the list of tasks is displayed in the checkedlistbox when the user clicks a button (the tasks change depending on the button they push) and the goal is to get the supply for each to appear in the listbox.
We will eventually be using databases, but for now I am trying to get it functioning with an array.
Here is the code I have currently for when the user presses the button for livingroom:

```
Dim livRoomItems As String() = {"sofa", "TV", "entertainment center", "coffee table", "end table", "book shelf", "living room floor"}
'declare an array of strings for tasks
Dim livTasks As String() = {"remove cushions and vacuum couch", "dust front and back of the TV", "wipe down entertainment center with furniture polish",
                            "wipe down coffee table with furniture polish", "wipe down end table with furniture polish", "wipe down book shelf with furniture polish",
                            "vacuum living room floor"}
'declare an array of strings for all supplies for any room
Dim livSupplies As String() = {"all-in-one cleaning spray", "furniture polish", "broom/dustpan and mop", "vacuum", "glass cleaner", "duster", "toilet bowl cleaner", "shower cleaner", "canned air"}
```

when the user clicks the button all of the items in the array livRoomItems appear in the checkedlistbox cbxRoomItems.

```
Private Sub btnLroom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLroom.Click

    'add array of items to the checklistbox for livingroom
    cbxRoomItems.Items.AddRange(livRoomItems)

End Sub
```

I am trying get the supplies associated with what the user checks in cbxRoomItems to show in listbox lbxSupplies by calling the correct index in the array for the item selected and then display the associated task to complete for that item in listbox lbxTasks.

I am able to get the array of supplies to be displayed in the listbox, but not the ones specific to what has been checked.
Here is what I have tried so far:

'this adds the living room supply array to the listbox - it works, but has duplicates
        'lbxSupplies.Items.AddRange(livSupplies)

```
    'This doesn't work 
    'For Each livRoomItem() As Array In cbxRoomItems.CheckedItems
    'lbxSupplies.Items.Add(supplies(0))
    'lbxSupplies.SelectedIndex = 0
    'Next

    'I tried this just for the first checkbox for living room, it does not work
    'If (cbxRoomItems.CheckOnClick = True) Then
    'livRoomItems(0) = lbxSupplies.Items.Add(supplies(3))
    'End If

    'determine the type of supplies needed for the checked living room items
    If (livRoomItems(0) = (cbxRoomItems.CheckOnClick = True)) Then
    lbxSupplies.Items.Add(supplies(3))
    ElseIf (livRoomItems(1) = (cbxRoomItems.CheckOnClick = True)) Then
    lbxSupplies.Items.Add(supplies(5))
    ElseIf (livRoomItems(2) = (cbxRoomItems.CheckOnClick = True)) Then
    lbxSupplies.Items.Add(supplies(1))
    ElseIf (livRoomItems(3) = (cbxRoomItems.CheckOnClick = True)) Then
    lbxSupplies.Items.Add(supplies(1))
    ElseIf (livRoomItems(4) = (cbxRoomItems.CheckOnClick = True)) Then
    lbxSupplies.Items.Add(supplies(1))
    ElseIf (livRoomItems(5) = (cbxRoomItems.CheckOnClick = True)) Then
    lbxSupplies.Items.Add(supplies(1))
    ElseIf (livRoomItems(6) = (cbxRoomItems.CheckOnClick = True)) Then
    lbxSupplies.Items.Add(supplies(3))
    End If
End Sub
```

Again - I am really new to visual basic and having a hard time finding a reference for what I am trying to do.

I appreciate the feedback greatly!!

Update:

I am having luck with :
Dim indexChecked As Integer

```
    For Each indexChecked In cbxRoomItems.CheckedIndices
        lbxTasks.Items.Add(livTasks(indexChecked).ToString)
    Next
```

but since I am not sure how to work around adding another room's array to the checkbox. I could make them into one massive array, but the buttons the user selects to pick a room would be useless.

Comment: If I understand it correctly you want to add the respective supply to another list box when you select one of the tasks? For instance when you check `vacuum floor` then `vacuum` will be added to the other list box?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  We are not here to write code for you,  If you do research, refine the code and repeat as necessary,  `luck` wont be an essential element in your code.

Comment: Visual Vincent
Yes - I am sorry if the first version of my post wasn't clear - I have revised it with the actual code I am using. I was trying not to make the post enormous :)
Thank you!